# Will items that are supposed to download to a folder that has been changed to a symbolic link download to where the symbolic link is linked to?

Tags: finder, data-transfer, symlink, logic

I'm trying to put the downloaded content for Logic Pro X on an external hard drive. I created the appropriate folders on my external and put corresponding symbolic links in the appropriate applications support folders. If I try to download more content through Logic Pro X, will it get downloaded onto my MacHD or onto the external hard drive?

Comment: Also, a little less important, will the packs that have already been downloaded to my external hard drive be marked off as installed on the Sound Library Manager?

Comment: Generally speaking, it should work.  If you can start with a very small download to see if it redirects following the symlink you can proceed with larger scenarios. As an example it worked in this case [ iTunes Unable To Backup iPhone](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/243479/itunes-unable-to-backup-iphone/243490#243490). Note that one comment said it didn't however they really didn't provide any diagnostic info so frankly I ignored it since it did work for the person asking the original question. I also have diverted downloads in other apps in the past the same way and it worked.

Comment: This makes sense. I tried it with a small download and it appears to have worked. The only reason I say appears is because the logic audio packs are fairly ambiguous in terms of where they go and what the audio files are specifically named, but no new folders were added on my MacHD so I'm 97% sure it worked properly.